# Can a Woocommerce product category URL contain "&"?

Tags: categories, urls

I am trying to display a product archive page and the product category slug has a "&" in the title but it doesn't work. I understand the & is used to do URL queries and works as a sort of separator.

I've tried the following:

```
product%26category
```

Which I hoped it would generate:

```
product&category
```

But it actually shows the %26 in the final URL, not the "&" sign.

I've tried adding %26 to the category slug, which upon saving shows a & sign, but then the URL shows just a 26.

Comment: You’ve pretty much answered your own question. The ampersand is a reserved character in URLs. You shouldn’t use it the way you’re describing. Think about how often you see the ampersand used like that in URLs. It’s probably never, right?

Comment: No I know, it was a client request and I wanted to be really sure...Thanks for your answer.